# Remove/add css classes on breakpoint with matchmedia.js

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, matchmedia

I have following code which works fine when the screen size is `770px` and below (as determined by breakpoints):

```
    var handleMatchMedia = function (mediaQuery) {
      if (mediaQuery.matches) {

         $j(".view-all a").removeClass("button");
         $j(".view-all").removeClass("view-all");

    } else {

        $j(".view-all a").addClass("button");
        $j(".view-all").addClass("view-all");
    }
},

mql = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 770px)');

handleMatchMedia(mql); 
mql.addListener(handleMatchMedia);
```

The problem is when the window is resized to `770px` and up I lose my classes.

How to achive to change class on window resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing what you're going for is changing the design page when media changes, by adding classes.

Simply using css and media queries will achieve this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 770px) {
  .viewall a {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

but if you truly want it too be handled with javascript I'll recommend using another class as marker, like `.adapt` and changing the code to:

```
var handleMatchMedia = function (mediaQuery) {
    if (mediaQuery.matches) {
       $j(".adapt a").removeClass("button");
       $j(".adapt").removeClass("view-all");
    } else {
       $j(".adapt a").addClass("button");
       $j(".adapt").addClass("view-all");
    }
},

mql = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 770px)');

handleMatchMedia(mql); 
mql.addListener(handleMatchMedia);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to cache your selectors. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/55b5x4s0/#base) as well :

```
var viewAll = $j(".view-all")
  , buttons = $j(".view-all a")
  , handleMatchMedia = function (mediaQuery) {
     if (mediaQuery.matches) {
       buttons.removeClass("button");
       viewAll.removeClass("view-all");
    } else {
       buttons.addClass("button");
       viewAll.addClass("view-all");
    }
  }
  , mql = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 770px)');

handleMatchMedia(mql); 
mql.addListener(handleMatchMedia);
```

Comment: Nothing. With your solution now classes stays no matter of breakpoint width.

Comment: create simple jsfiddle with your code. when you cache selector ( ie `viewAll=$j(...)` it just save reference to all nodes, and you are free to add/remove classes over those elements.
Also if all you want is to change some styles consider using media queries right into css.

Comment: added jsfiddle to show that this code is indeed working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to save the needed classes in a `data-770-classes` attribute.

```
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
   buttons.removeClass(buttons.attr('data-770-classes'));
   viewAll.removeClass(viewAll.attr('data-770-classes'));
} else {
   buttons.addClass(buttons.attr('data-770-classes'));
   viewAll.addClass(viewAll.attr('data-770-classes'));
}
```

I assume `$j` creates a `jQuery` object.

The HTML would look like:

```
<div class="view-all" data-700-classes="view-all">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.className += "button"` to add class and `.className = ""`to remove class, here's the code you need:

```
var viewAll = document.getElementsByClassName("view-all")[0];
var buttons = viewAll.getElementsByTagName("a");
var handleMatchMedia = function (mediaQuery) {
  if (mediaQuery.matches) {
     buttons.className += "button";
     viewAll.className = "";
  } else {
     buttons.className += "button";
     viewAll.className += "view-all";
  }
}
var mql = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 770px)');

handleMatchMedia(mql); 
mql.addListener(handleMatchMedia);
```